# Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK Unity5.2 Facebook SDK 7

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

Hi guys i am working on a game with a Facebook login however i keep stuk on this error

Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK

here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;

public class FBholder : MonoBehaviour {

void Awake ()
{
    if (!FB.IsInitialized) {
        // Initialize the Facebook SDK
        FB.Init(InitCallback, OnHideUnity);


    } else {
        // Already initialized, signal an app activation App Event
        FB.ActivateApp();
    }
}

private void InitCallback ()
{
    if (FB.IsInitialized) {
        // Signal an app activation App Event
        FB.ActivateApp();
        // Continue with Facebook SDK

    } else {
        Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
    }

    FB.ActivateApp ();
    var perms = new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends"};
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
}

private void OnHideUnity (bool isGameShown)
{
    if (!isGameShown) {
        // Pause the game - we will need to hide
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    } else {
        // Resume the game - we're getting focus again
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}

private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) {
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        // AccessToken class will have session details
        var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
        // Print current access token's User ID
        Debug.Log(aToken.UserId);
        // Print current access token's granted permissions
        foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) {
            Debug.Log(perm);
        }
    } else {
        Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
    }
}

 }
```

i have added my app id in the Facebook settings in unity

i use this documentation 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/examples

Answer (score 2):

Find FacebookGameObject.cs .. then replace this:

```
public void OnInitComplete(string message)
        {
            this.Facebook.OnInitComplete(message);
            this.Initialized = true;        
        }
```

with this:

```
public void OnInitComplete(string message)
        {
            this.Initialized = true; 
            this.Facebook.OnInitComplete(message);          
        }
```

This mistake will be fixed in the next patch..